# Is there a simple way of turning an object name into a string, and then adding that string to a property in the object called objName?

Tags: javascript, object

I would like the following code to return "The beagle's name is Snoopy daSilva".

I think what I need is to be able to access the object name and turn it into a string, maybe save it as a property, and then add it to the fullNameDescription (where it currently says ???this object name???)

Even better, could I save the object name as a string to a property within the actual object, something like this.objName = ???

```
function Dog(firstName, secondName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.secondName = secondName;
  this.fullNameDescription = function(){return("The " + ???this object name??? + "'s name is " + this.firstName + " " + this.secondName)}
}


let beagle = new Dog("Snoopy", "daSilva");


console.log(beagle.fullNameDescription())
```

Comment: Not in any sane manner. A script should not depend on its variable names in any fashion.

Comment: afaik, there is no valid way to make it, even with Reflect or other hacks. Could you pass another parameter to Dog constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function Dog(firstName, secondName, type) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.secondName = secondName;
  this.type = type;
  this.fullNameDescription = function(){
    return `The ${type}'s name is ${firstName} ${secondName}`;
  }
}

let beagle = new Dog("Snoopy", "daSilva", “beagle”);

console.log(beagle.fullNameDescription());
```

Comment: Yes but I want it to work for different instances of dog. Lets say I create a nother instance of dog: let terrier = new Dog("Rover", "Rogers"), I want fullNameDescription to return "The terrier's name is Rover Rogers" and not "The beagle's name is Rover Rogers". I think the other commenter was correct and I should add a third parameter called dogType or something.

Comment: Updated answer, but yeah, you should use another parameter to indicate the type of dog ( in this example at least)